# How to write a recursive function in R with a list as input and output

Tags: r, recursion

I want to represent the following evolution of a polygonal chain using a **recursive function** (no particular reason for that fact):

```
step 1. The chain starts with 2 line segments and is (of course) opened;
step 2. close the polygonal chain with a new line segment;
step 3. open the polygonal chain;
step 4. GOTO 2
```

I want to obtain as a result, a list with "time (step number)", "indication of the state of the chain (opened/closed)", "number of line segments (edges)". I created the following script, but one of the mistakes I made was not having a stop condition. I thank the commentators of my post. I think I solved the problem. Below I will try with a new script to answer my own question.

```
recursive.d <- function(d){
  t <- d[[1]]
  a <- d[[2]]
  k <- d[[3]]
  a <- !a  
  t <- t + 1
  k <- ifelse(a, k + 1, k)
  d <- list(t, a, k)
  d <- rbind(d[], recursive.d(d[]))
  return (d)
}

d_ini <- list(0, TRUE, 2)
recursive.d(d_ini)
```

But in fact, the output is `Error: C stack usage  7970888 is too close to the limit`.What have I done wrong?

Comment: 1) Why do you need recursion? 2) What/where is your stop condition in your code? 3) Can you actually describe what you want to do - your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There is no basis case. You hit the line `d <- rbind(d[], recursive.d(d[]))` (which involves a recursive call) before you hit any line which can actually return. Of course you blow the stack. This is the recursive equivalent of an infinite loop.

Comment: 1) I need recursion because I want to use it in this particular case. It is not for practical reasons or to obtain certain results; 2) I don't have a stop condition. I tried to use k == 5 as a stop but the function only returned 5; 3) This code does not make sense because it is in a form very abstract with letters. I am trying to produce a list where the first member counts time (1,2,3,...), the second oscilates between TRUE or FALSE, and the third counts a number that depends on the other 2 memvbers of the list.

Comment: But if I do return(recursive.d) at the end of the function the result is no better.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a stop condition? What do you expect the output to be? And are you just saying you want to use recursion because... you want to use recursion and there isn't a reason you need to use it?

Comment: You showed what the output should be like -- but you didn't show what the input should be or describe how the input is supposed to be related to the output. If you want help, perhaps you can edit your question a bit to explain better just what this function is supposed to do.

Comment: I expect the output to an infinite series. The reason to use recursion is philosophical.

Comment: You can't store an infinite series in a list like that. So the answer is that what you want to do can't be done.  You could probably roll your own generator so that you can have it keep producing more elements when you need them but what you're asking to do just isn't a thing in R.

Comment: Stacks are not infinite. Unless you stop with some basis case you will just succeed in crashing the R interpreter rather than generating an infinite series.

Comment: If your interests are philosophical then I suggest posting here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/  If you have an actual use case then describe that and we'll try to help out.  Otherwise I think this should be closed.

Comment: The input is d_ini. But I will edit the question to be more clear later.

Comment: @Dason Sorry but I read your suggestion to post in philosophy.stackexchange.com as rude. It is possible to compute n factorial or Fibonacci series with a recursive or non-recursive function. What is the reason to do it in one or another way? I have nothing against philosophy, on the contrary, but I am not a philosopher. I do not think it is necessary but later I will describe my use case if you do not close my question before.

Comment: @sbac There is nothing wrong with recursion and there is nothing wrong with exploring how recursion works in R. Functional programming makes heavy use of recursion, and R is at least partially a functional language. The problem with your question is that it wasn't clear what you were trying to do with recursion. If we don't know what your function is supposed to do then it is hard to say how it can be fixed. I look forward to reading your edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Representation of the evolution of desire
based on Gonçalo M. Tavares, "Desire" in "O Sr. Swedenborg"
(in Portuguese) [link to book](http://www.caminho.leya.com/pt/literatura/romance/o-senhor-swedenborg-e-as-investigacoes-geometricas/)

```
recursive.d <- function(d){
  t <- d[[1]] # time
  a <- d[[2]] # desire true/false
  k <- d[[3]] # edges
  k <- ifelse(a, k + 1, k)
  a <- !a  
  d <- list(t+1, a, k)
  if (t == 10) return(NA) # stop condition
  else
  d <- rbind(d[], recursive.d(d[]))
  return (d)
}

d_ini <- list(1, TRUE, 2)
desire <- rbind(d_ini, recursive.d(d_ini))
colnames(desire) <- c("Time", "Desire", "Edges")
desire
```

Results:

```
  Time Desire Edges
d_ini 1    TRUE   2    
      2    FALSE  3    
      3    TRUE   3    
      4    FALSE  4    
      5    TRUE   4    
      6    FALSE  5    
      7    TRUE   5    
      8    FALSE  6    
      9    TRUE   6    
      10   FALSE  7    
      NA   NA     NA
```

Comment: ... so you just wanted to generate the first ten elements of your data? You could easily include the number of elements to generate as a parameter in your function.

Comment: Yes, these are only the first ten elements. I put a stop condition of ```t == 10```. I think I solved the problem. Now I want to represent it in a chart series of open/closed polygons. Sorry I didn't your observation about the number of elements as a parameter. Good idea! I'm trying to depict a piece of literary literature with R :-)